# Application_Error global.asax not catching all errors (.Net Thread)

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, global-asax, unhandled-exception, application-error

We are logging exceptions in application_error at global.asax, but we have witnessed that if there is any exception raised from a background thread this is not being catch there (application_error )

The only way it seems to catch is adding:
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
in the Global.asax Application_start.

My concern is If an exception is being catch by application_error, will it be also catch by unHandledException. This will create unnecessary duplicate entries in my logs table. So i just want the exception to be handled by either one of them

Comment: I have seen that it will not add any duplicate entry. usually AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException will also terminate the app pool also, so it is a good catch for errors coming from thread etc